# How do you add/remove rows dynamically? [WPF]

Tags: wpf, grid

Here is an [example](http://www.studeravidare.se/om-hogskolan/meritvarde/teknikprogrammet-a-f).

[image: Preview]

"Ta bort" - Remove

"Lägg till rad" - Add

Would you use a DataGrid or a Grid? How do you add/remove rows dynamically (when the application is running)? [WPF]

Comment: `ItemsControl` with custom `ItemTemplate` and items source bound to `ObservableCollection <T>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGrid, ItemControl or ListBox, it's up to you.

Let's assume every row represent a instance of some class named "MyClass".

Firstly, you should create ObservableCollection in your ViewModel.

```
 Public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyClassList=new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
```

In Xaml, you may have a ItemsControl like this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyClassList}" Margin="10">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <!--  Here is how you represent your data. But you should have a remove button here. -->
      <Button Content="Remove" 
         Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And a button to add new instance.

```
 <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
```

In your ViewModel, AddCommand is to add a new instance.RemoveCommand is to remove instance.

```
    private void ExecuteAdd()
     {
        MyClassList.Add(new MyClass());
     }

    private void ExecuteRemove(object param)
     {
        MyClassList.Remove(obj);
     }
```